# ros and rasperypie combination

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I,m new to ROS and have a conceptual problem. Is it correct For a robot with Rassperpie microprocessor to use ROS for programming it? I mean the rasperipie has its own other languages.
I know ROS is language-independent to some extent. But is this combination (ros + rasperripie) a tested and well documented combo?
If yes , please guide me find it!
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202231/ros-and-rasperypie-combination/) by [Sam](https://answers.ros.org/users/21550/sam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2015-02-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS on Raspi works - slow but it works...
Wait for Raspi2-Hardware and Ubuntu 14.04 ARM.

If you have already an old Raspi with raspian installed and running, try to learn the Python programming language.

Notice: ROS is not a language - it is more like LEGO for robotics applications.

Happy robotics
Christian

---

Originally posted by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) with karma: 390 on 2015-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0